# Проблемно работает PHP функция mail(), отправляет письмо через 60 секунд

Tags: php, ubuntu, email, sendmail

Столкнулся с проблемой отправки почты с помощью PHP функции mail().
Проблема заключается в том, что при отправке письма скрипт исполняется 60 секунд и затем успешно отправляет письмо. Сервер на Ubuntu 18. С чем это может быть связано?
Вот код:

```
$to  = "my-email@gmail.com";
$subject = "Подтверждение регистрации на Site"; 
$message = "<h2>Это письмо было отправлено для подтверждения e-mail.</h2><p>Если это сделали не вы - немедленно обратитесь к администратору сервера.</p><p>Это автоматическое письмо, пожалуйста не отвечайте на него.</p>";
$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; UTF-8 \r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: site.ru <from@site.ru>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: info@site.ru\r\n";
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) === true) {
echo json_encode('success');
} else {
echo json_encode('error');
}
```

Comment: sleep(60); стоит гденибудь?

Comment: А как ты определил, что письмо отправляется через 60 секунд?

Comment: Почтовый сервер стоит локально? Посмотрите логи сендмейла. Может он тупит (большая очередь, медленные днс-запросы). Может быть на почтовике стоит защита от спама с грейлистингом

Comment: Отправляй через smtp, будет почти мгновенно.

Comment: Рашен Беар, по секундомеру.

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашёл сам: нужно было в файле hosts корректно прописать домен.
Полное решение нашёл тут: www.alphadevx.com/a/372-Fixing-slow-performance-of-sending-mail-from-PHP-via-Sendmail